# Nonetype has no len()

Tags: python, error-handling, non-type

d=("adf": 1, "bdc":2,"cdsd":4)

def longest_key (d):

longest None

for key in d: if not longest or len (key) > len (longest):

longest = key

return longest

print(longest_key(d)).

When i do this the program is fine and no error occurs but

d=("adf": 1, "bdc":2,"cdsd":4) def longest_key (d):

longest = None

for key in d: if len (key) > len (longest):

longest key

return longest print (longest_key(d)).

When i do this it shows type error object of type Nonetype has no len()

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please reformat your code.  (I would've tried to edit for you but the edit queue is full)  Also please include the full error traceback.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve its formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You set `longest` to None and you're trying to get its length. In the second function, it errors because you don't have the `if not longest` condition. The first function works because short circuit evaluation means that `len(longest)` will not be evaluated.